# How to represent nested iteration as list comprehension?

Tags: python

I want to use list comprehensions instead of using nested for-loops. How would I represent the following structure using a list comprehension?

```
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letter_list = [ ]
for a_word in word_list:
    for a_letter in a_word:
        letter_list.append(a_letter)
```

I tried

```
letter_list = [letter for letter in word for word in word_list]
```

But that returns an error:

```
NameError: name 'word' is not defined
```

What is the proper way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: reverse the 2 expressions `[letter for word in word_list for letter in word ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it the other way around: **swap the iterations**:

```
  [letter for word in word_list for letter in word]
#  \_ __/ \_________ _________/ \________ _______/
#    v              v                    v
#  yield       outer loop            inner loop
```

So you need to define `for` loops in the order in which you would define the `for` loops in the imperative style. The same holds with filters (`if`s in the list comprehension). These also have to be written in the same order.

The idea is that if you read `for <pat> in <iter>`s left-to-right, then the `<iter>`s have to be defined before using these (for instance in the `<pat>`terns).